# iphone live video broadcast to other iphone

Tags: iphone, video, device, mirror

I have 2 iphones. I would like to record live video from one, and show that video live on the screen of the other. Is there a way to do this locally (ie not bouncing through a server somewhere) maybe using local bluetooth/wifi, with gamecenter perhaps?

I'm open to existing apps too, if they exist. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and probably *should*) use [Bonjour](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) for handling communications between two iPhones. You can modify this tutorial example to send the recorded video from one device to another.

**Update:** Looks like a StackOverflow user [has managed to do just this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279122/streaming-images-over-bonjour-between-two-ios-device), although not perfectly.

Comment: I realize I wasn't clear and have edited my question -- I wish to send live video from one to the other. Would this still work using bonjour? The problem I thought I would have is that you have to bring up the video app view controller within your app, and maybe you can't get that data and pipe it over realtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible with an existing app. Have a look at **[Airbeam](http://appologics.com/airbeam)**.

I'm running it on two iPhones, one connected to the other through Personal Hotspot sharing. The app allows me to view and record video and audio on either device from the other, over ad-hoc wifi.